# C# pinvoke - class derivation

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am taking a guess here, but I don't imagine you can use C# and derive from a class declared in a C++ header, can you?

I think pinvoke let's you call native C or C++ functions from C#, not derive from and instantiate classes.

Vendor is requesting that I use pinvoke to derive from a class in their native C++ library, and call a function in their library with my derived instance as an argument.

Can someone verify that it isn't possible?

Comment: C++/CLI or native C++?

Comment: That's not possible with *native* (i.e. unmanaged) C++

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not normally, but there's voodoo like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c/

Comment: Correct, not possible